# What is the difference between unsafe.Sizeof(T) and reflect.TypeOf(T).Size()

Tags: go

I have written a program to check the difference between the unsafe.Sizeof() and reflect.TypeOf().Size()

For numerical types like int and float64, unsafe.Sizeof() shows 16 where as reflect.TypeOf().Size() shows 8

when I checked the go packages reference for reflect, it showed

// Size returns the number of bytes needed to store

// a value of the given type; it is analogous to unsafe.Sizeof.

if it is analogous, why both methods return a different value?

```
func describe(i interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("Type = %T, value = %v size = %d reflect.Size = %d \n", i, i, unsafe.Sizeof(i), reflect.TypeOf(i).Size())
}

func main() {
    s := "Hello World"
    describe(s)
    i := 55
    describe(i)
    k := 1.1
    describe(k)
    strt := struct {
        name string
    }{
        name: "John",
    }
    describe(strt)
}
```

Output

```
Type = string, value = Hello World size = 16 reflect.Size = 16 
Type = int, value = 55 size = 16 reflect.Size = 8 
Type = float64, value = 1.1 size = 16 reflect.Size = 8 
Type = struct { name string }, value = {John} size = 16 reflect.Size = 16
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unsafe.Sizeof(i)` is giving you the size of `interface{}` every time, not the size of `i`'s dynamic type. `reflect.Typeof` is *meant* to take an `interface{}` and look at what's inside, so it works as you expect.

If you called `unsafe.Sizeof` directly without the `describe` function and its conversion to `interface{}` you would see a different result.

Comment: @noob-Programmer: `unsafe.Sizeof(i)` in `main()`. The problem is that the `i` parameter of the `describe` function is of type `interface`. The unsafe.Sizeof an interface is 16 bytes (at least on most platforms).